# How to get Google Sign in for Android working with Hosted Domains

Tags: android, google-signin

I am having trouble working with Google Sign in for Android when setting [the Hosted Domain](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#setHostedDomain(java.lang.String)) parameter. When it is set, there is no restriction on what domain the user can sign in with, which contradicts the documentation.

I am expecting what Google does on a browser when the HD parameter is set on the request_uri, which limits the sign in to accounts only on that domain, however, I only get the generic sign-in flow which allows all accounts.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .setHostedDomain("example.com")
            .requestIdToken("WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

*Note: I am not looking for work arounds for this issue, such as checking the domain after signing as we are trying to address this issue due to user experience complaints.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable sign in for specific domains you have to configure your project on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

From my experience, and as far as I know, the setHostedDomain("example.com") option will not restrict the email input on the login screen, it will only restrict by showing you the email addresses with that domain already registered on the device.